# Тормозит Eclipse и Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема: при использовании ADT Eclipse или Android Studio у меня неслабо тормозит комп. Есть ли какие-то решения?

Comment: Мне кажется, очевидно - купить новый.   
Более простой вариант - поставить SSD.

Comment: написано оно на java, поэтому ответ очевиден - доставить оперативки в первую очередь (загрузку можно и подождать). Ну хотя бы 8 гигов. ssd - это для более быстрой загрузки.

И самый простой случай - просто почистить комп - пыль с вентилятора и подобное. Иногда очень сильно помогает, особенно, если комп при нагруженной работе сильно гудит.

Comment: Операционная система? Начинка компа? Установленная версия JAVA? Что, кроме ADT Eclipse или Android Studio, запущено? Или мы тут должны это так, телепатически понять? Может, вы и ответ тогда телепатически поймете?